# Port Forwarding Local FTP Server

Tags: networking, router, ftp, port-forwarding

I have two routers set up I  my home, the default Verizon router that comes with my ISP and a Linksys EA6350 which I set to cascade my Verizon router. The linksys router also comes with a built in ftp server that I am using with my external hard drive. The problem with this is that since this router is not connected to the Internet, the ftp server is for my LAN only. When i tried to port forward on my Verizon router, I forwarded port 21 and to 192.168.1.4 which is the LAN ip address of the linksys router. But now when I test if the port is open on canyouseeme.org,its showing that port number 21 is blocked. Can someone help me fix this please?

Comment: Is Verizon connected to Linksys yellow port? http://bit.ly/1NCsx8O In that case, you probably need to open port(s) of Linksys to&fro WAN.

Comment: The Verizon is connected to the Lan port of the linksys. It is a Lan to lan connection

Comment: Yes I can connect internally using Chrome. I'm away from home at the moment but the router model is mi424wr Rev e

Comment: For what it's worth, the port forwarding is working after a closed inspection of the Verizon logs. The problem lies in the linksys router.

Comment: FTP uses two ports, 21 to open communication with the server, and 20 to transfer data.

Comment: Port 20 is no issue AFAIK. I'd rather check to have TCP selected for port 21, I forgot to mention on earlier comment.

Answer (score 2):

*Thoughts*

- **Something may be blocking port 21 for some reason.** From what I can google, Verizon doesn't block port 21 but you may wish to try a different control port (e.g. 2222) for the outside connection anyway. This may add a tiny layer of security as well from people scanning port 21 for hackable FTP servers.
- **Toggle connection modes of your client.** There is "active" (PORT) and "passive" (PASV) mode FTP and this essentially governs who gets to tell whom what address/ports to use (the client or the server). This makes a difference. For FTP to work behind Firewalls/NAT, PASV mode is often necessary/preferred.
- **You may need to open more ports**. Port 21 is just a control port. Most data transfer takes place on a range of higher ports (e.g. 9000-10000) which you may have to forward in your router as well (this occurs in "PASV" mode). With "PORT" mode, you may need to open/forward Port 20 for additional data communications.

Comment: According to [this scheme](http://www.slacksite.com/images/ftp/activeftp.gif) server's port 20 starts communication, thus there shouldn't be need for port forwarding. Moreover, that port is needed just on active FTP, is this the case?

Comment: While it's is true that outgoing connections are unlikely to be blocked, note step 4 where the client responds to port 20. I would say this warrants perhaps considering opening/forwarding the port (since incoming communications are often blocked). Perhaps I worded this too strongly. Note this scheme for PASV -- http://www.slacksite.com/images/ftp/passiveftp.gif -- where port 20 is omitted. A random port substitutes for the data communication that normally occurs on port 20 for active FTP from the server (so no, it isn't needed).

Comment: Correct, port 20 is involved just for active FTP. According to TCP, reply should go thru the router, as communication started from LAN.